# The code does not execute properly. Try to figure out why

Tags: c

```
int multiply(int a, char *b) 
{
return a b;
}
```

The code does not execute properly. Try to figure out why. 
c program language

Thank your kindhearted help !
 the question has been solved simply by me, thank everyone!

```
int multiply(int a, int b) 
{
return a*b;
}
```

Comment: `return a * b;`

Comment: `return a * *b;`

Comment: exactly what is it you expect to send in in the `char*` parameter? If it is a string, converting it to `int` can be done with `atoi`

Comment: First, try to compile your code. Execution is the second step.

Comment: What do you intend to do? Multiply an `int` with a `char*`? Or is it *concatenation* you wish to do.

Comment: Please edit into your question a description of what the code is _expected_ to do. Should the function signature be: `int multiply(int a, int b)` instead?

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one error in there.
First, you can't return two variables in the same function, you should return **a** or the content of the pointer that the variable **b** in pointing to.
So, you could either use:

```
return a;
```

to return the variable a.

or you could use

```
return *b;
```

to return the content of the adress that b is pointing to.

If you want to multiply, as the name of the function, you should use:

```
return a*(*b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function need to return an integer

```
int multiply(int a, char *b)
```

but you try to return an int (a) and a char* (b)
if you want to return b (and only b) use

```
char *multiply(int a, char *b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create a variable that the result will be the multiplication of the parameters and then return the value like the created variable, as I showed.

```
int multiply (int a, int b) {

    int result;

    result = a * b;

    return(result);

}
```